# Select Mysql Table based on other table field value

Tags: mysql

I wonder if its possible to make query like this one:

```
SELECT cs.platform,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM general_list as loc WHERE loc.platform=cs.platform) as indexed,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cs.table     as loc WHERE loc.platform=cs.platform) as sandbox
FROM (
    SELECT platform, table
    FROM states
    WHERE visible=1
) as cs
```

For each iteration in the main select, I need to take the table name from cs.table to info from such table.

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: Sorry, it was a bug! I have fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: The field 'table' in states holds the table names. The issue is that in the second select (sandbox) I want to use the name of the table in the field (cs.table).

Comment: Please, it is not clear, add your table schema.

Comment: I suppose you're trying to use the content of `table` field on a FROM sentence. You should have a look at dynamic queries.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to "dynamically" use a tablename is via a Stored Routine in which you do `CONCAT(...)` to build the SQL, plus `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` to then perform the constructed SQL.

Needing to do this is *usually* a sign of poor schema design.  Please explain the schema and why you went that direction; we may be able to help 'fix' it.